# Is it possible to upgrade the 'instant on' 20GB SSD used for caching on Acer Aspire?

Tags: ssd

I have recently purchased an Acer Aspire s3 391. One of the major appeal of this ultrabook was the fact that it sports a 20GB SSD that is caching Intel's 'instant on' technology to allow the device to ready for use in 1.5 seconds.

My question is: Is that mSATA ssd? If so, may I just upgrade it with higher volume mSATA ssd? and still make a great use of 500gb hdd.

Any light on this dark matter would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the maximum size of the SSD can be 64GB according to this Intel Website:

[image]

http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm

Comment: Dear Magicabdre1981, thanx for info, found it interesting and will look into it for my desktop rig. My question concerns specifically ultrabook ssd. But cheers anyway!